# Divide code into smaller components ruins state

Tags: reactjs, react-datepicker, react-hook-form

I have following code:

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-datepicerhook-u2vv1

As you can see there is a working date picker and a none working date picker. The two date pickers are very similar so I would like to make a new component that just takes the parameter as name. However there is something in my state that goes wrong on the one I denormalized. Any pointers why and how to solve it?

Comment: Sure? It is not like I have code that is working and would like a review. But code that does not work and need to know how to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You bound one more layer of arrow function, so add one more `()` when binding to props.

Change from this

```
as={<FormDatePicker />}
```

to

```
as={FormDatePicker()}
```

Comment: Just one question. Why is it that my component needs to be declared as function, where as the DatePicker are added as a tag? Is it because I implemented mine as an arrow function, and react-datepicker implemented it as a class?

Comment: @ThomasSegato Nope, not related to classical or functional, you used the `= props => {`, there is a param there as well as the props `as` doesn't have any passed value. It may differ from other APIs like `onChange` which has an `event`. So for this situation, if you write like `=> {` you can use the `as={<FormDataPicker />}` or `as={FormDataPicker}` as normal